# Linux C program - HEX how can I Prefix with 0x

Tags: c, linux, hex

This program converts string to Hex.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char text[] = "thank you";
  int len = strlen(text);

  char hex[100], string[50];

  // Convert text to hex.
  int i,j;

  for ( i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j+= 2) {
    sprintf(hex + j, "%02X", text[i] );
    printf("0x%X ", text[i] ); //this prints fine
    }
  printf("'%s' in hex is %s.\n", text, hex); //'thank you' in hex is 7468616e6b20796f75.

  // Convert the hex back to a string.
  len = strlen(hex);
  for (i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++, j+= 2) {
    int val[1];
    sscanf(hex + j, "%2x", val);
    string[i] = val[0];
    string[i + 1] = '\0';
  }

  printf("%s as a string is '%s'.\n", hex, string);

  return 0;
}
```

But I need  `0x74, 0x68, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x6B, 0x20, 0x79, 0x6F, 0x75`
or assign to array

unsigned char key[] = {0x74, 0x68, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x6B, 0x20, 0x79, 0x6F, 0x75};

How to store to a string this hex value.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please clarify your question? Is there a problem in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `0x` in your `sprintf()` format, and increase the amount you increment `j` accordingly.

```
for ( i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j+= 5) {
    sprintf(hex + j, "0x%02X ", text[i] );
    printf("0x%X ", text[i] );
}
```

Then you need to allow for this when scanning it. Skip over the first two characters, and then increment by `5`.

There's also no need to make `val` an array, you just need a single `int` variable. And you can add the null terminator at the end of the loop, not each time through the loop.

```
for (i = 0, j = 2; j < len; i++, j+= 5) {
    int val;
    sscanf(hex + j, "%2x", &val);
    string[i] = val;
}
string[i + 1] = '\0';
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/8P2TuN)

Comment: it prints only one hex 'thank you' in hex is 0x74. I need to store in array  key[] = {0x74, 0x68, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x6B, 0x20, 0x79, 0x6F, 0x75}; How to do this

Comment: It works for me, see the demo link. Are you sure you included the space after `0x%02X`?

Comment: You can use `int key[len/5];` before the loop and then `key[i] = val;` in the loop.

Comment: You can use `%4X` to read a 4-character hex string including the `0x` (or `0X`) prefix.  Or, indeed, you can use `%4i` to read up to 4 characters as hex (if it starts with `0x`) or octal (if it starts with `0` and not `x`) or decimal.